# Как сменить язык раскладки для kivy-приложения на android

Tags: android, python, kivy, клавиатура

Создал небольшое приложение под андроид с помощью kivy. Возникла проблема при использовании TextInput. При запуске приложения непосредственно на устройстве(и на этапе отладки, и на уже собранном .apk), при попытке ввода в любой TextInput отсутствует возможность выбора русской раскладки. Пытался использовать свойство text_language: "ru_RU", но результата никакого.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что в системной раскладке клавиатуры нет кнопки смены языка. Кроме того в доступных языках нет русского. Решением стало создание собственной раскладки с помощью классов VKeyboard и TextInput.